# How to add user tags when publish video?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am going to publish video with user tags via postman by using facebook graph api.
First of all, I created media object container and got object's id.
Second I published post by using facebook graph api.
I added user tags via postman to publish picture.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{facebook_api_version}}/{{instagramAccountId}}/media
{
"access_token":"***",
"caption":"hello world",
"image_url":"***",
"user_tags": [
    {
       "username": "gravityblue",
       "x": 0.4,
       "y": 0.2
     },
     {
       "username": "erwan",
       "x": 0.3,
       "y": 0.2
     }]
}
```

It worked well so I added user tags like below to publish video.

```
{
"access_token":"***",
"caption":"hello world",
"video_url":"***",
"media_type": "VIDEO",
"user_tags": [
    {
       "username": "gravityblue",
       "x": 0.4,
       "y": 0.2
     },
     {
       "username": "erwan",
       "x": 0.3,
       "y": 0.2
     }]
}
```

But user tags didn't added to video at instagram.
I searched solution in many ways but didn't find.
Who can help me and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details from the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#publish-with-tagged-users